# Opa Bundle with aws s3 configuration

Tags: amazon-s3, open-policy-agent

I am new to opa server.
I am working on using opa as authorizer for multiple policies and use case is that I upload multiple policies to s3 bucket and then each policy has his own link like /opa/example/allow or /opa/example1/approve.
Now I want to use different requests coming to use this link along with data to check whether they are allowed for specific policy or not.

I am little confused with config as I was going through opa docs. Can someone guide me for same. Following is config I am using and whenever I am hitting opa server it is giving blank response. I have taken this from some blog but not sure if it will work or not.

config.yaml

```
  bundle-s3:
    url: https://opa-testing1.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/
    credentials:
      s3_signing:
        environment_credentials: {}
```

inside this bucket I have a bundle with rego file as follow :

```
package opa.examples

import input.user
import input.method

default allow = false

allow { user = "alice" }

allow {
    user = "bob"
    method = "GET"
}
```

opa server I am running using : opa run --server -c config.yaml

Request I am hitting is on : localhost:8181/v1/data/opa/example/allow

Can someone help me how I can achieve my use case here and some blogs or examples will be very useful

Comment: package name becomes part of the URI. Can you try witth /v1/data/opa/examples/allow. I see an 's' missing in the URI you shared.